# Excel export fails when it is opened in excel 2013

Tags: excel, apache, format, apache-poi

Am trying to convert FO with FO: table along with style attributes to excel. Am trying to export into multiple sheets. This works fine when I export to excel (.xls) and open in 2007 excel format. But when I open in 2013 then first two sheets comes up fine, however in sheet 3 onward style (background color, border width) are not coming up. Is this issue with apche poi jar? I tired with poi jar 3.13 version also. Issue remains same.  Please help.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell, but... Quick guess - did you make sure you created your cell styles up-front and re-used them? Excel has a hard low limit on the number of cell styles, they must be re-used not re-created each cell

Comment: I have an input file which is a .FO. This has FO:Table tags and other related tags. Am using this FO file to generate an output file .xls. The output file getting generated and when I open in Excel 2007 it looks fine. But when I open in Excel 2013, I see that after sheet 3 cell styling is not getting applied.

Comment: What code are you using to process the FO file?